# How to delete data from iPhone without being able to recover it again

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to sell my iPhone5, I have captured photos through its camera. Before selling I deleted all of my private pictures but I am worried that someone else will recover it.
My question is what should I do to delete photos permanently from iPhone5 without its recovery again.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is definitely not a programming question and really belong in Ask Different.

Comment: In the Settings app, go to General -> Reset and tap "Erase All Content and Settings". This will nuke the key used for "full disk encryption" on the flash memory and nobody will be able to recover anything unless they have access to your backups. More details: https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back up options :

1. You should use apple iCloud to store all your data which will be connected with your apple id online and can be restored any time.
2. Use iTunes to back up all your data to your local system.

[Reference](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204136)

---

Post 1 or 2 delete or [factory reset](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-factory-reset-an-iphone/) your phone, which will wipe out all data and then it would be safe to sell it.

Comment: thanks @max please tell me whether i can wipe all my data without option1 and option2

Comment: option 1 and 2 is for backing up, post which you peform factory reset to wipe out all data, never forget to back up data before you do a factory reset.

Comment: ok dear i will try it, i have another question, early i tried to erase all data from sitting>general>erase all --- it took 2 hours but the process didn't complete and waiting wheel image continues for 2 hours. then i restart it forcefully and all the data was still present in it, can i say it is due to i didn't took backup

Comment: you will have to post a new question for this. Please accept my answer if this works.